# EF Core: Create an object by passing an injected DbContext object as parameter

Tags: c#, object, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a .Net Core MVC project and understand that how the dependency injection works for our MVC controller as shown below, but same like I wanted to create an object for my own class by calling the same injected interface/class as a parameter.

```
public class ShiftsController : BaseController
{
  ShardingDbContext _dbContext;

   public ShiftsController(ShardingDbContext ShardingDbContext) : base(ShardingDbContext)
  {
   _dbContext = ShardingDbContext;
    ViewBag.Menu = BuildMenu();
  }
```

I have injected the DbContext into my Startup.cs file as below,

```
 //Entity Framework Core
 services.AddDbContext<ShardingDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString), 
 ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

The ShiftsController is a C#-MVC controller and the DbContext is working perfectly when I run my app and go to Shift's page in my application, but when I try like below-given code, it's not working and gives an error. So I don't know how to pass the registered class's object while creating an object by using "new" keyword.

```
public class JobScheduler
{
  ShardingDbContext _dbContext;


  public JobScheduler(ShardingDbContext ShardingDbContext)
  {
      _dbContext = ShardingDbContext;

  }...
```

This is my own class and tried to create an object for the class JobScheduler as shown below.

```
  JobScheduler  jobs = new JobScheduler();
```

So now I don't know how to pass the EF core's DbContext's object to the constructor JobScheduler, the DI works fine for the controller but not for a normal class. Can anyone help with this and I am eagerly waiting to understand this logic as well?.

Comment: A class has to inherit the BaseController.  A controller is the object that gets the response to the query and parses the results.

Comment: How often does your jobScheduler run?

Comment: @Amir every 30 minutes it has to run the job

Comment: @Jdweng, I don't want to call this from controller but from startup.cs file only wanted to start the job

Comment: How can you fill the dbContext if you do not query the database?  So you want to do is send a request to database when the application is started to query database.  The response to the query is done from the controller.

Comment: @jdweng, Yes I wanted to fetch some info from DB when the job starts but I don't want to run this job from controller but I wanted to run this job when the app starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs class, and I did not change anything in the JobSchedulerclass and passing the DbContext object from the service provider as shown below, thanks to everyone who tried to help with this question.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 { 
   ...
   ...

   JobScheduler job = new 
   JobScheduler(services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider
   .GetService<ShardingDbContext>());
   
   job.Start();
  }
```

Comment: @ Amir, thank you for your answer, I got the idea from your post :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that if the job is reoccuring every 30 minutes (as you stated in another commet) the reference to `ShardingDbContext` in `JobScheduler` is kept all the time which should be avoided as DbContext instances should be very short-lived and reusing them over a longer period of time can cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Nannanas, I totally agree but can you add your answer with a short-lived DbContext object?

Comment: Dear MdAslan, this solution makes DbContext be singleton :). Singleton DbContext as unignorable side effects.

Comment: Yes, Right now I made it as a singleton but later I will change this scope. this is just POC so I have to check whether it's possible or not but  We will come late for optimization.

Comment: @MdAslam I've updated my answer to contain an example

Answer (score 0):

You are right: Your DI works fine but your `ShardingDbContext` is not passed into your `JobScheduler` because you are not using DI to instanciate `JobScheduler`. Whenever you are explicitly creating an object instance using the `new` keyowrd you are not using DI.

You have two options:

1. Wherever you are calling `new JobScheduler()` let DI inject you a `ShardingDbContext` through the constructor and pass it to JobScheduler like so `new JobScheduler(shardingDbContext)`
2. Register `JobScheduler` to the dependency injection as well and let DI build up the whole chain so you don't need to call `new JobScheduler()` but rather get a `JobScheduler` injected directly wherever you need it

**Edit**

As requested here is the example for a timed job using a short lived DB context:

```
public class TimedBackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public TimedBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        timer = new Timer(async state => await ExecuteAsync());
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        timer.Change(0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();

    private async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var job = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyJob>();

            await job.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // log error here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyJob` class wil look something like this:

```
public class MyJob
{
    private readonly ShardingDbContext dbContext;

    public MyJob(ShardingDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task Execute()
    {
        // Your logic goes here
    }      
}
```

Then you register your classes in the startup like so:

```
services
    .AddHostedService<TimedBackgroundService>()
    .AddScoped<MyJob>();
```

Now you have a job which runs every 30 minutes and uses a short lived db context.

Comment: Why not do it the correct way by sending a request to the database (query) and fill context with the response from the query using a controller.

Comment: @ Nannanas Can you please provide me a sample code? or how to create an object of DbContext?

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I agree we can use a controller to trigger the job but we want to work this job every 30 minutes automatically, but if we use a controller to run the query then how the controller will be called automatically? we have to do some action from view for the page or controller right? then only the controller will call the job, but I don't want that job to dependent on any classes or controller or pages.

Comment: The controller does not trigger the job.  It is used to parse the response.  A request is sent to get the response which starts the job.  You just want to trigger the request which can be sent as a JobScheduler or from inside an application as a request.  The request and response share the same connection and are text messages.  So you want to capture the response and the parse the response.  So the JobSceduler can send the request and then call an application to parse response.

Comment: @MdAslam sorry for the late response - you should never create an instance of DbContext yourself but let DI build up the whole chain for you. If you want the job to run every 30 minutes add an IHostedService (where you can require an `IServiceProvider` in the constructor and it will be provided by DI). This service has a timer and everytime when the timer elapses creates a scope through the service provider and retrievies a fresh DbContext using `GetRequiredService`.

Answer (score 0):

Register your JobScheculer like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<JobScheduler>();
```

then use your dbContext like this:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

   public JobScheduler(IServiceProvider provider)
   {
       

   }...


   public (or private etc) DoYourJob()
   {
        using (var scope = provider.CreateScope()) 
        {
            var dbContext = scope.GetService<ShardingDbContext>();
            //use it here
        }
   }
```

Comment: I have followed your code but I am getting a runtime error: InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service ... from singleton

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your code and the place that the exception raises. I will follow that <3. I checked it again and it's ok. Something smells wrong in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much Amir, I have found my solution based on your answer but I have added my answer as well, I thought to tick your answer but unfortunately, it's not helped me directly due to I have mentioned .Net Core in the question.